# suspend AND lock screen on closing lid in arch/systemd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, suspend, screen-lock

what is the most straightforward way to lock the screen AND suspend when closing the lid? I'm using event hooks in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and successfully suspend upon closing the lid. However I'm lost when it comes to the locking part - am I supposed to enable some screensaver service and how can I trigger two events at once in `logind.conf`?

Comment: Outside of scope so I'm commenting: in i3 it's very easy to assign keybindings to commands. Since `mod+L` was already assigned to `blurlock` for me, it was easy to have `mod+S` be `blurlock && systemctl suspend -i` instead. So, not when closing the lid, but works very well to choose whether I just want to lock, or lock and suspend.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a couple of examples in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Sleep_hooks).

Basically, it involves creating a service file for your screen locker and ensuring it is hooked to either the `suspend`, `hibernate` or `sleep` targets.

If you use a simple screen locker like [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock), `/etc/systemd/system/lock.service` would look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock the screen on resume from suspend

[Service]
User=jason
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/slock

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Other examples on the wiki have more complex options, including shutting down and bringing up other services, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that example but did not realize the `ExecStart=/usr/bin/slock` bit refers to locking at first glimpse.

Comment: If I suspend and come back, my X display manager has a screen lock, that's great. But what about my ttys? What if I'm logged in, and I suspended and I forgot to exit from my ttys, people could switch to there and continue their operations.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai you want [physlock](https://github.com/muennich/physlock) then...

Comment: That looks great, how could one use physlock while disabling KDE's lock screen? I wouldn't want to have to unlock twice, through physlock then KDE's lock screen.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai no idea: I avoid DEs for precisely that reason...

Comment: This does work, but only if you are the only user of the system. A cleaner solution is to use `xss-lock` (available in Debian, Arch Linux; also Fedora next week) and run that as a user together with `i3lock` or `slock`.

Comment: @MartinUeding Not so: I use this one a multi-user system and it works fine...

Comment: But only with one graphical session, right? Otherwise you would not have display 0.

Comment: @MartinUeding No with two. Recent versions of systemd mean you can remove that variable and your session will work fine with multiple instances of X running.

Comment: Okay, I only have a problem with fixing DISPLAY. if one can get around that, is fine

Comment: FYI I am using i3lock and had to add ``--nofork``

Comment: @MartinUeding and @jasonwryan, `User` is hardcoded. The assumption that this machine will only be used by `jason` (or someone who knows his password, like his girlfriend, for example). Ideally, we'd want `User` to be whoever initiated the suspend, but I haven't found a solution for that (yet).

Comment: By the way, `xss-lock` is nice but it looks for an X session, which I sometimes don't have. Maybe I can modify it and recompile it.

Comment: Note that this will fail if the laptop unexpectedly cannot suspend (you may not notice, since you closed the lid): https://geoff.greer.fm/2018/01/02/linux-laptop-locking/

Comment: I wonder why you could not use [systemd --user](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User) instance for the job and put the unit file e.g. in `~/.config/systemd/user/` so not superuser privilege is needed?

Comment: `user` units cannot get triggered by `system` targets directly -- so there's no straightforward way for user units to start when locking/sleeping. [systemd-lock-handler](https://gitlab.com/WhyNotHugo/systemd-lock-handler) works around this by translating `system` events to `user` events.

Answer (score 5):

While jasonwryan's reply is correct, it is incomplete.  In order to safely lock after suspending, instead of before - where a non-root process may prevent the kernel from suspending, you must add a **Before=** instance which forces **systemd** to wait for the **ExecStart** call to *slock* to start before suspending.  Using **sleep.target** covers suspend, hibernate, and hybrid sleep.

```
[Unit]
 Description=Lock
+Before=sleep.target

 [Service]
 User=mustapha
 Environment=DISPLAY=:0
 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/slock

 [Install]
-WantedBy=suspend.target
+WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `openrc` with `elogind` is there an alternative solution (which is not systemd dependent):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
#
# /lib/elogind/system-sleep/lock.sh
# Lock before suspend integration with elogind

username=lerax
userhome=/home/$username
export XAUTHORITY="$userhome/.Xauthority"
export DISPLAY=":0.0"

case "${1}" in
        pre)
            su $username -c "/usr/bin/slock" &
            sleep 1s;
            ;;
esac
```

ref: https://gist.github.com/ryukinix/bd0c1ddcbbafdb4149ae70e41b7c822b

I'm posting this because was very difficult to find it a proper way that it works and this thread appears on first results of google about "lock after suspend" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

All answers presented here have one fundamental flaw: They set the DISPLAY variable irespectively of what seat/session is active. And they involve writing your own systemd service file.

Thus, I suggest using the fact that logind (part of systemd, I believe) sends DBUS notifications before suspending. If you subscribe to these messages, you can start the screen locker from within you desktop environment and really lock the correct screen/session.

Additionally, there are programs like https://github.com/swaywm/swayidle that already implement this. For example, I've got this in my window manager's config:

```
exec swayidle -w \
    timeout 300  'swaylock -i $wallpaper' \
    timeout 600  'swaymsg "output * dpms off"' \
    resume       'swaymsg "output * dpms on"' \
    before-sleep 'swaylock -i $wallpaper' \
    lock         'swaylock -i $wallpaper'
```

To automagically lock the screen after some time, before suspending and whenever screen locking is requested. I've set `HandleLidSwitch=lock` in /etc/systemd/logind.conf to have my laptop locked when I close it.

Edit: You will also need to enable DBUS support your desktop session. I launch my window manager (sway) directly from the console, so my call became

```
exec dbus-run-session sway
```

Similarly, you could probably (I did not properly test this part) start your X window manger, i3 in the example using the following line in you `~/.xinitrc`

```
exec dbus-launch i3 > /dev/null
```

Edit: Please note, that this answer is given *much* later. I do not if this was already possible when these answers were given and do not wish to discredit any of the other authors.