# Lock screen on suspend with Awesome WM

Tags: fedora, suspend, screen-lock

I currently use Fedora 22 with a plain Awesome WM session. I can lock the screen with say `slock`.

There are ways to lock the screen on suspend with the system wide instance of `systemd`, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81692/suspend-and-lock-screen-on-closing-lid-in-arch-systemd) for instance. The problem with that approach is that it uses a hard-coded `DISPLAY` variable which is not a nice thing to do. The `systemd --user` instance cannot depend on system targets, therefore one cannot couple a user task to `sleep.target`.

On Ubuntu I have been using `xss-lock` for this task but that is not packaged in Fedora 22 yet. There one runs this tool that will spawn a process when the computer suspends.

Is there some nice way to automatically lock the screen on suspend that works out of the box with Fedora 22?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `slock` for that. Slock supports a second argument. So you may want to pass your suspend command.
For example: `slock s2ram` or `slock systemctl suspend -i`
You can even specify your own script to run some commands after locking the screen.

Comment: This is the wrong way around. I want to be able to close my laptop without locking it manually. Then if I open it, the screen should be locked. That's how it works on KDE (which I am using by now). Manually locking before suspend has the possibility of forgetting to lock.

Comment: Any solution for that @MartinUeding? I'm still interested.

Comment: @ManoelVilela: I have packaged `xss-lock` for Fedora at some point, so that should work there as well. But I switched back to KDE and therefore this is no longer a concern for myself.

Comment: I made a fix. But only aim people that don't use systemd: https://gist.github.com/ryukinix/bd0c1ddcbbafdb4149ae70e41b7c822b. But I think that can be systemd-wise portable since this init system ate logind as well.