# IceWM. How to lock screen after laptop lid is closed?

Tags: password, screen-lock, acpid, icewm

I use the IceWM window manager.

I would like the screen to lock after closing the laptop lid.

I've found a couple of guides that looked promising ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260737/switch-off-display-and-lock-screen-in-xfce-power-manager-when-laptop-lid-is-clos), [2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts)) but unfortunately didn't work for me.

Maybe there is a solution that I'm currently missing?

Comment: what is the actual problem? ... is the lid state being detected?

Comment: @jsotola I followed the instructions in the guides precisely, but after I open the laptop lid my screen lock program `slock` does not activate :(

Comment: I did not ask if screen lock is activated

Comment: @jsotola You asked what is the actual problem.
How can I determine whether the lid state has been detected?

Comment: check the kernel logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IceWM doesn't have a built-in screen lock feature, you'll have to install an extra application for that, e.g. `xlock`.

To invoke xlock on lid close please consult with this answer: [suspend AND lock screen on closing lid in arch/systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81692/suspend-and-lock-screen-on-closing-lid-in-arch-systemd)

Comment: Thank you :)
I've created the `/etc/systemd/system/lock.service` file, pasted the content from jasonwryan's answer, changed the `User` name, made the file executable.
Still doesn't work :(
Maybe you can see what I missed?
P.S. Of course I have the `slock` program installed.

Comment: Just creating a unit is not enough.

Comment: What else needs to be done?

Comment: Google: how to enable systemd unit